# Networkstream not responding

Tags: c#, networking, stream

I'm trying to send an image over a networkstream this is my client code:

```
   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        TcpClient client=new TcpClient();
        client.Connect("127.0.0.1", 10);
       NetworkStream  ns = client.GetStream();
        Bitmap screen = GetDesktopImage();//generate a screenshot.
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        screen.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);

        byte[] byteCount = BitConverter.GetBytes((int)ms.Length);

        ms.Position = 0;
       ns.Write(byteCount, 0, byteCount.Length);
        ms.CopyTo(ns);
        ms.SetLength(0);



    }
```

this is the server:

```
    private void Start()
    {
        TcpListener listen = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 10);
        listen.Start();

        NetworkStream ns = new NetworkStream(listen.AcceptTcpClient().Client);
        byte[] temp = new byte[4];
        ns.Read(temp, 0, 4);
        int count = BitConverter.ToInt32(temp, 0);   
        byte[] buff = new byte[count];
        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ns);

    }


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread th = new Thread(Start);
        th.Start();

    }
```

I dont see nothing on the picturebox and i guess the program hangs here- `pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ns);`just added a breakpoint there and it's not working.
**Only when i close the client program and stop the debugging ,then i can see a image on the picturebox on the server side.
Why is it?Any ideas?

Comment: *pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ns);just added a breakpoint there and it's not working* - Does that mean it never gets to the breakpoint, or doesn't go past it?

Comment: It's only not going past it . before it works. @Amit

Comment: DId you try grabbing the bytes to the `buff` instead?

Comment: @Amit yep.still no luck

Comment: So if you try to read "count" bytes of the stream (`ns`) right after you allocate the array, the call to `ns.Read(buff, 0, count)` won't return untill the client is closed? That's very odd...

Comment: @Amit yea... very weird man...

Comment: What is the length of byteCount (`byteCount.Length`), and what value does `count` resolve to on the server side?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87085/discussion-between-slashy-and-amit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that `Image.FromStream` does not know to stop reading when it has drawn the full image. Maybe the PNG format does not even allow for that. You need to give a stream to `Image.FromStream` that has a limited size. The easiest way would be to use `BinaryReader.ReadBytes(count)` to read the exact amount of bytes needed.

`ns.Read(temp, 0, 4);`: This is a bug because it assumes that the read will return exactly 4 bytes. This might not be the case. Again, use `BinaryReader.ReadInt32` to safely read an int.

Better yet, abandon custom serialization formats and use something like protobuf length prefixed. Or, HTTP or WCF.

Comment: never worked before with http or wcp.. so i guess that's what im going to use :)  I have another question really similar and related to this. should i open a new issue or may i only edit the post above and you can help me? thanks for everything! @usr

Comment: You can ask your related question right here in the comments.

Comment: I actually want to send additional information about the image,for example the location it should be drawn at. for example (400,829). both are int.do i have to write each ns.write(//the numer converted to byte) and to use network everytime or may i write it into a regular `memorystream` and than copy the entire content? @usr

Comment: You can do both. Thanks to Nagling both will usually result in the same network packets being sent. But maybe you want to disable Nagling. In that case it's better to do one big send operation. The more fields you want to send the more attractive protobuf becomes.